# Visual Studio 2022 problem after upgrade to last version 17.2.6

Tags: .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

like title after upgrade, VS detect many error like this:
[image]

[image]

But the code build successfully.
I try to repair Visual Studio 2022 but this not solve the problem.
Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/IDE-shows-error-CS0518-for-SystemString/10094515?space=8&q=cs0518&sort=newest

Comment: thank you i removed obj forlder now its ok

Comment: I just updated and have the same problem. Some are saying this resolves by deleting the *obj* folder, but my solutions have many such folders.

Comment: @JonathanWood Start a bash shell and change your current working to the root of your solution(s), then execute the command ``rm -rf `find . -name obj` ``

Comment: @GoWiser bad idea. There might be other directories (like from npm packages or git/github directories) that use `obj` directories. If you delete those, it might be a helluva task to fix it. (Talking from experience)

Comment: @JHBonarius Then replace the find with `find . -name obj | grep -v NameOfSubPathToExclude`. The point is that it's easy create a command line to do it. There are many variations on the theme I try to illustrate. And always check the results of your find, before you do the deletion.

Answer (score 12):

This issue is caused not by the Visual Studio update from 17.2.5 to 17.2.6, but by the update from .NET SDK 6.0.301 to 6.0.302 (which is automatically done during the Visual Studio upgrade). Intellisense is still looking for the code analyzers in the old SDK directories.

To find this, you should actually not look at the errors, but at the warnings (seeing you have 56 warning, I guess you tend not to look at them. It's a **very** good habit to keep the number of warnings at 0).
Inbetween the warnings you should see something like:

> Warning CS8034 Unable to load Analyzer assembly C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\analyzers\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.NetAnalyzers.dll: Could not find a part of the path ‘C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\analyzers\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.NetAnalyzers.dll’.

How I fixed it: by manually opening the properties (alt-enter) of each problematic project. If you do that, it automatically fixes the paths.

Hans Passant's fix (deleting all the `obj` directories) seems way simpler, and might be a good thing to do on any Visual Studio upgrade. (Note, only delete the build `obj` directories, not those of dependencies, like git/github/node-modules/etc)

edit: Note that there is a side-issue with .NET SDK 6.0.302, where source generators run twice, which breaks anything that relies on them, like the WPF- and WinUI community toolits.

edit2: Microsoft has notified that these issues should be solved with the next release/update.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers from the Package Manager Console removed the warnings for me.

NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers -Version 3.3.3

See: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers/#versions-body-tab